Enrich Table Using Translation Table Xceptor Input Format
I have a data table:

I have a translation table:

I want to create colB in my data table using a Reference Data Lookup enrichment in Xceptor.
When I try to do this, I am unable to get the desired output.

When I have Reference Type set to Replace entire values (ignore duplicates) and Blank Value Handling set to Treat as wildcard. I get this table as a test output:


When I have Reference Type set to Replace embedded values (ignore duplicates) and Blank Value Handling set to Treat as wildcard. I get this table as a test output:

In the first failed test case no value is added. In the second failed test case the key value for colA is added instead of the value for colB.
I am trying to debug this error, but I am not seeing many other options to configure this differently. I have replicated the documentation examples and gotten different results. There is possibly some configuration error, but I have been unable to identify.
